# Which material are fake eyeballs made off?

Tags: effects, props, kill-bill

I recently watched the Kill Bill movies. In both movies Beatrix plucks out an eye from an opponent (Elle Driver and one of the crazy 88). I'm curious about which material fake eyes in Kill Bill (or in other movies) are made of.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on needs, generally they are made from acrylic, glass, Latex or silicone.

Acrylic and glass can give the glossy look to the prop eye, but latex and silicone can give it a spongy texture.

Of the Swedish film [Thriller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thriller_%E2%80%93_A_Cruel_Picture#cite_note-Nicholas-2), lead actress Christina Lindberg said [in an interview](http://www.dbcult.com/printed-media/christina-lindberg-interview/) Director Bo Arne Vibenius used an actual human cadaver for the eye "surgery" scene.

Comment: When are you going to expand your answer? :)

Comment: @Charmin ah, life...it so gets in the way. I will work on it so more in about 12 hours.

Comment: No problem :-) I don't want to rush you ;-)

Comment: @Charmin, I spent a few hours looking for an authoritative how-to source, but I couldn't find anything. I did find a ton of prop eyes for sale on ebay and other online venues that all list the products I've mentioned already. I can corroborate based on that evidence, but nothing written ATM. My best answer won't include anything about the process of making, or the decision behind why to use one product over another.